# Having trouble figuring out where to put the "share" icon

Tags: lean-ux

I am having trouble figuring out where to put the share icon. For context, this is a page where users can talk to an AI and we want a share button.[image]

Comment: I agree to @Johannes solution, but in the first place I'd try to understand why (if) share button is needed in this scenario? I believe you're struggling to find the place for the share button due to the fact that it's hard to understand why is it needed. Will it share the contact's information, phone number, will it just copy a link to the profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot I assume that X, LinkedIn and Medium are linking to the appearance of "John Allen" on those sites. So it doesn't make sense to put it there. The other possible option to put it, would be next to the two buttons. There it would make the most sense to me, as both these buttons are actions the user can perform. But sharing is probably less relevant / important than "Add Friend" and "Chat with Me", so I would locate it right of the two buttons.
But in the end it all depends on the importance of each of the actions the user can do. This hierarchy of importance, should be reflected visually in the design.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Helps a lot. The share will populate a modal to share via socials or copy link.